# how to implement pagerank for one iteration?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, pagerank

I'm trying to implement the pagerank algorithm for a single iteration.
[Based on my colab here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NTjHjXJ_cGMgFax4sZmvFu7_JpuzMPc4#scrollTo=zghQ-AhXYmP4&line=3&uniqifier=1) the formula is defined as:

=∑→+(1−)1

which i tried to implement as:

`r1 = (beta * (r0/degi)) + ( (1 - beta) * 1/node_count)`

however, on cross-checking with the networkX implementation I get different values. The [nx source code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/algorithms/link_analysis/pagerank_alg.py#L158-L172) is a bit hard to grok as its for multiple iterations with dangling values.

my code (better viewed on colab)

```py
def one_iter_pagerank(G, beta, r0, node_id):
  # TODO: Implement this function that takes a nx.Graph, beta, r0 and node id.
  # The return value r1 is one interation PageRank value for the input node.
  # Please round r1 to 2 decimal places.

  degi = G.degree[node_id]
  node_count = G.number_of_nodes() # correct?
  r1 = (beta * (r0/degi)) + ( (1 - beta) * 1/node_count)
  print('r1:', r1)

  # crosscheck
  # alpha == beta? (without= 0.128, with=)
  r2 = nx.pagerank(G, max_iter=1, tol=0.1)[node_id]
  r3 = nx.pagerank(G, max_iter=1, tol=0.1, alpha=beta)[node_id]
  print('r2:', r2, '\nr3:', r3)


beta = 0.8
r0 = 1 / G.number_of_nodes() # assign base value?
node_id = 0
print('r0:', r0)
r1 = one_iter_pagerank(G, beta, r0, node_id)
```

which returns multiple values:

```
r0: 0.029411764705882353  # base value?
r1: 0.007352941176470587  # my calculation
r2: 0.13427287581699343   # nx calc with no alpha
r3: 0.12810457516339868   # nx calc with alpha
```

So where is my implementation wrong / so different from nx results?

The colab is based on the [Stanford CS224W course CS224W: Machine Learning with Graphs
here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate one iteration of PageRank, you need the out-degree (or just the degree since the graph is acyclic in this case) of the neighbouring nodes of `node_id`. The value you are calculating is the degree of `node_id` itself. The following works for me.

```
def one_iter_pagerank(G, beta, r0, node_id):
  # TODO: Implement this function that takes a nx.Graph, beta, r0 and node id.
  # The return value r1 is one interation PageRank value for the input node.
  # Please round r1 to 2 decimal places.

  r1 = 0

  neighbors = [n for n in G[node_id]]
  degrees = [d for _,d in G.degree(neighbors)]

  for d in degrees:
    r1 += beta*(r0/d)

  r1 = round(r1 + (1-beta)/G.number_of_nodes(), 2)

  return r1
```